# Unable to create an object of objects within phantomjs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, phantomjs

I am using `phantomjs` to write a script which extracts some features of the requests and responses of a webpage. I have adaped the script from `phantomjs` example over [here](http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html) and the `netsniff.js` example referenced in the page. To match the request with its particular response, I create an object of objects called page.resources indexed by means of the urls. The trouble is that the object is not being set in my code. My code is copy/pasted below.

Over here I first create a `page.resources` object, and then on each call to `onResourceRequested`, I insert an object with certain attributes. When I try to access just after this inner object has been created, I am unable to do this. Also, when I try to access the same object in `onResourceReceived` I get no output. Could anyone please help? I have tried to debug this using `console.log` at different places of the code but I can't really figure out what could be going wrong.

```
"use strict";

var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: netsniff.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {

    address = system.args[1];
    page.resources = {}
    page.redirectedURLs = {}

    page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
        console.log("Resource requested: " + req.url)

        page.resources[req.url] = {

            url: url,
            redirected: null, //will be set in response
            redirectedURL: null, //will be set in response
            HSTS: null,
            maxage: null,
            includeSubdomains: null


        };
    //Can't access the object over here
        console.log("accesing page resources" + page.resources[req.url].url);


    };


    page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
   //Can't access the object over here either
      for (var key in page.resources) {
         if (pageresources.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         console.log(key + " -> " + page.resources[key].url);
        }
      }
   };

    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        }


    });

    page.onLoadFinished = function(response) {
        phantom.exit()

    };


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
page.resources[req.url] = {
        url: req.url, // was just "url" which was undefined
        redirected: null, 
        redirectedURL: null,
        HSTS: null,
        maxage: null,
        includeSubdomains: null
};
```

Comment: God, thank you so much!! Do you have any advice on what is the best technique for debugging (except for `console.log`) when using `phantomjs` with `javascript`

Comment: To check for errors in your script, use phantomjs v1.9.8 first, then run it in v2.x. The reason is in version 2 [errors are swallowed by qtwebkit](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12973). Also always use [page.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) callbacks to check for errors in `page.evaluate` sandbox.